# How to convert date from mm/dd/yyyy to mm dd, yyyy

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to convert date from 07/02/2019 to July 07, 2019. My input value is 07/02/2019 I want to compare with target value July 07, 2019....Please help me on this...

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

```
    String sDate1="07/01/2019"; 
    java.util.Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(sDate1); 
    System.out.println(date1);
```

Output:Mon Jul 01 00:00:00 IST 2019 which is not my expected value

Comment: Don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The latter is notoriously troublesome, the former poorly designed too and both long outdated. Also despite the name a `Date` doesn't represent a date. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    Date data = sdf.parse("07/02/2019");
    String newDate = output.format(data);
    System.out.println(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you use:

```
java.util.Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(sDate1);
```

to **parse** a date that comes in as String.

Then you **print** that date without any formatting information.

Thus the answer is quite simple: define a pattern for **formatting** a Date object as string! Same rules, same patterns. Just not *parsing*, but formatting for printing!

In other words: you already know the concept, you used a formatter to turn a String into a Date. Now simply turn that around, and provide a pattern to a formatter to turn a Date into a string!

Comment: Tried different ways but couldn't figure out

Comment: @User2080 Obviously "here is the code" answers are less work for you, so I am fine with your accept, but wondering: is there anything I could add to make this answer at least upvote worthy? As I think *explaining* the right thing is (long term) always the better answer than "here is the code".

Answer (score 0):

Parse your input date

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sDate, formatter);
```

Similarly parse your target date

```
DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate targetDate = LocalDate.parse("July 07, 2019");
```

Or better yet, define your target date without using a string

```
LocalDate targetDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JULY, 7);
```

Compare

```
if (date.equals(targetDate)) {
    System.out.println("Same date");
}
```

`LocalDate` also have methods `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

This answer is entered from my tablet without trying the code out, so please forgive the typos.